# How to timeout a process of which I am catching the output in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have a script:

```
timeout 5 ./cl_launcher -p 0 -d 0 -f ${file} > ./ResultsOpt/$(basename "$file" .c)_test.txt
```

The process ./cl_launcher outputs test results for a file that I want to capture. However, occasionally cl_launcher doesn't terminate, so I want to make sure that it gets killed if this is the case. The current script doesn't timeout. Any ideas?

Here is the full script:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2 #Called with a directory of .c programs as an arg
3 export LC_ALL=C
4 
5 #Get DIR and OPT 
6 DIR="$1"
7 echo "with or without optimizations?"
8 read OPT
9 COUNTER=0
10 
11   if [ "$OPT" = "with" ]; then
12     #Get kernel results and store
13     mkdir ./$(basename "$DIR")_ResultsOpt/
14     for file in ${DIR}*.c; do
15       timeout 5 ./cl_launcher -p 0 -d 0 -f ${file} > ./$(basename "$DIR")_ResultsOpt/$(basename "$file" .c)_test.txt
16     COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
17     echo "Process ${COUNTER} finished at `date +%s`"
18     done
19 
20   elif [ "$OPT" = "without" ]; then
21     #Get kernel results and store
22     mkdir ./$(basename "$DIR")_ResultsNoOpt/
23     for file in ${DIR}*.c; do
24       timeout 5 ./cl_launcher -p 0 -d 0 -f ${file} ---disable_opts > ./$(basename "$DIR")_ResultsNoOpt/$(basename "$file" .c)_test.txt
25     COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
26     echo "Process ${COUNTER} finished at `date +%s`"
27     done
28 
29   else
30     echo "Enter with or without"
31   fi
32 
33 echo "finished"
```

Comment: Get the pid, add a timer, kill when the timer expires.

Comment: "occasionally cl_launcher doesn't terminate": there is no answer for this unless you can determine why. I suspect it is waiting on some driver (network drives and cdroms are notorious for this). But the script is rather meaningless unless you describe what ./cl_launcher is doing.

Answer (score 2):

If `timeout` doesn't work, it seems likely that killing the process after a limited time won't work either.  My speculation is that the `timeout` command was sending signal 2 and the target process was somehow ignoring or dodging that, and so you need to try a different signal.  Maybe try something like

```
#!/bin/bash
#Called with a directory of .c programs as an arg
export LC_ALL=C

#Get DIR and OPT 
DIR="$1"

while true; do
    read -p "With or without optimizations? " OPT
    case $OPT in
      with)  opt=""; res="ResultsOpt";  break;;
      without) opt="--disable-opts"; res="ResultsNoNopt"; break;;
      *) echo "Enter with or without";;
    esac
done

COUNTER=0

#Get kernel results and store
mkdir ./$(basename "$DIR")_"$res"/
for file in ${DIR}*.c; do
      ./cl_launcher -p 0 -d 0 -f ${file} > ./$(basename "$DIR")_"$res"/$(basename "$file" .c)_test.txt &
      pid=$!
      for sig in 0 0 0 0 2 0 15 0 9; do
          sleep 1
          kill -0 "$pid" || break   # Still there?  Hello?
          case $sig in 0) ;; *) kill -$sig "$pid" ;; esac
      done
      wait "$pid"
      COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
      echo "Process ${COUNTER} finished at `date +%s`"
done
#echo "finished"
```

Notice also how the script was significantly refactored to avoid repeating code.  I would furthermore delegate the optimization choice to an option instead of requiring interactive input.

Comment: Try killing it with 2, if it survives, try again with 15, then finally if it's still there kill it with fire.  Edited the answer to clarify this -- thanks for asking!

Comment: Sigterm is likely to do less than Sigint though. You may as well just not use either and kill -9 it.

Comment: It's not necessarily a question of "less" vs "more" but of "trapped" vs "not trapped" so I would try both before going berserk with 9.  If the program needs to do any sort of cleanup, the 9 will prevent that, so it should generally be avoided.

Comment: I'd probably but just test before hand which ones work but yeah probably. Anyway your answers like an improved version of mine so i'm gonna delete mine and +1 :)